# How to use ByteBuddy in a java project

Tags: byte-buddy

I made a simple project of java to test ByteBuddy . I typed exactly the same code in a tutorial made by Rafael Winterhalter but it showing some errors

```
    1) ByteBuddyAgent cannot be resolved.
    2) type cannot be resolved to a variable.
    3) builder cannot be resolved.
    4) method cannot be resolved to a variable.
```

I added the byte-buddy-1.7.1.jar as a referenced library.

```
public class LogAspect {

public static void main(String[] args){
    premain("", ByteBuddyAgent.installOnOpenJDK());
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    int sum  = calculator.sum(10, 15, 20);
    System.out.println("Sum is "+ sum);
}

public static void premain(String arg, Instrumentation inst){

    new AgentBuilder.Default()
    .rebase(type -> type.getSimpleName().equals("Calculator"))
    .transform((builder, typeDescription) -> builder
            .method(method -> method.getDeclaredAnnotations().isAnnotationPresent(Log.class))
            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(LogAspect.class).andThen(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE)))
            .installOn(inst);
}


public static void intercept(@Origin Method method){
    System.out.println(method.getName()+" is called.");
}

}

@interface Log{

}

class Calculator {
@Log
public int sum(int... values) {

    return Arrays.stream(values).sum();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a very outdated tutorial of the 0.* ara. Use an IDE to check your compile-time errors and [check the webpage](http://bytebuddy.net) for more recent tutorials.